# Is it possible to use update_state and progress_observer within a function executed by a Celery task instead of directly inside the task itself?

Tags: python, django, django-celery

I am developing a Django app that browses a website, selects a comic, and downloads it in the background with Celery. In the `task.py` file, I have a `download_comic()` function decorated with `@shared_task()`. The function checks the URL's hostname and uses different child classes of the base class `FileHost` to download the file. The actual download is done inside the class method, not on the task function.

I came across this article (https://buildwithdjango.com/blog/post/celery-progress-bars/) that suggested using `task.update_state` and `progress_observer.set_progress` for progress monitoring. However, I am not sure if I can use these functions inside a class method or not.

Here's a snippet of the `FileHost` class and `download()` method for reference:

```py
class FileHost:
    def __init__(self, url):
        self.url = url
        r = requests.get(self.url)
        self.soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")

    def download_file(self):
        # Implement the file download logic here
        raise NotImplementedError()

    def download(self, filename, direct_link):
        response = requests.get(direct_link, stream=True)
        temp_path = Path('/tmp') / filename
        if 'Content-Disposition' in response.headers:
            content_disposition = response.headers['Content-Disposition']
            temp_path = Path('/tmp') / content_disposition.split("=", -1)[-1]

        if response.status_code == 200:
            total_size = int(response.headers.get('content-length', 0))
            downloaded_size = 0
            with open(temp_path, "wb") as file:
                for chunk in response.iter_content(chunk_size=4096):
                    if chunk:
                        file.write(chunk)
                        downloaded_size += len(chunk)

                        # Calculate the progress percentage
                        progress = int((downloaded_size / total_size) * 100)

                        # HERE I SHOULD USE task.update_state OR progress_observer.set_progress I'M NOT SURE
        else:
            raise Exception("Error:", response.status_code)

        return temp_path
```

Can I still use `task.update_state` and `progress_observer.set_progress` inside a function executed by a Celery task and not inside the Celery task itself?

PS: The AI-suggested edit was amazing!

### Edit:

Forgot to add this in case it's important
The task is executed with signals

```py
@receiver(post_save, sender=Comic)
def after_comic_model_save(sender, **kwargs):
    download_comic.delay(sender.id, sender.download_link)
```